# ora-01403 at run time environment Only

Tags: oracleforms

after i had alert one of my tables column and change its type from 
number to varchar2 and changing the data type also for the text item

I tried also the data block wizard to refresh the data block and also 
write the `DISPLAY_ERROR` at each step but nothing show up !

I had tried to delete the FMX file and recompile the form and generate the FMx file but thats was not help !!

> frm-40508 oracle error unable to insert record !

at run time environment Only but when I run the from from developers 
it is works fine !

i know it should be sample error to solve but all my tried had fail 
whats the problem please !

is their any cache or something I need to refresh it ?!

should I delete the whole datablock and re-builded cause of that little change ?!

Comment: 1. Check tables constraints where you want to update/insert record.
2 Read http://www.dba-oracle.com/sf_frm_40508_oracle_error_unable_to_insert_record.htm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just for sharing my problem that I was navigating through multiple forms using 
`OPEN_FORMS` which is by default has `NO_SHARE_DATA_LIBRARY` I had replace it with 
`CALL_FORM` which is has same parameters as `OPEN_FORMS` but it is allow forms to do update insert and delete transactions for more understanding Please refer to oracle forms  builder help search for `OPEN_FORM` AND `CALL_FORM` key words

Thanks